# How to offset background-position vertically only?

Tags: html, css, w3c

I am making a navigation bar using `<ul>`. The css code is following:

```
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  background: url(/images/nav.png) no-repeat;
  width: 666px;
  height: 60px;
}
  .nav li {
    font-size: 0px;
    background: url(/images/nav.png) no-repeat;
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav .navhome {
    background-position: -31px 0;
    left: 31px;
  }
  .nav .navA {
    background-position: -152px 0;
    left: 32px;
  }
  .nav .navB {
    background-position: -273px 0;
    left: 33px;
  }
  .nav .navC {
    background-position: -394px 0;
    left: 34px;
  }
  .nav .navD {
    background-position: -515px 0;
    left: 35px;
  }
  .nav .navhover {
    background-position-y: -60px;
  }
  .nav .navcurrent {
    background-position-y: -120px;
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

There is also jQuery function that when the mouse hovers on one button, a class `.navhover` is added, so that the background image will be move up, and thus show a different part of the entire image; so is class `.navcurrent` (the current page).

I implemented it on MAC and tested it in Chrome. But when I validated the code I found that `background-position-y` is not standard (in fact, I also used `background-position-x` for those 5 buttons). Since there is x-offset for each button, `background-position: 0 -60px` for `.navhover` will always show the first one. Also, I tried `background-position: inherit -60px;` and it doesn't work. So how to only vertically move the background position?

Another question, `pointer-events` is also not standard, and it doesn't work in firefox and opera. Is there an alternative way to disable the click function on the button with class `.navcurrent`?

Comment: Can you post the code to jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent click event on .navcurrent:

```
$(".navcurrent").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

and for the background position, why can't you have instances for each class:

```
.nav .navD:hover {
    background-position: -515px -60px;
}
```

Comment: For hover, it's ok. But how to do with "current"?

Comment: @xuc  Do you mean active? Then you use the pseudo-class "active" in place of hover. If that's not what you mean, can you try explaining further? thanks